# Microsoft Graph API: SharePoint: Get items list in "default Drive" of "root Site"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

**Overview**

I am familiar in using **Microsoft Graph API** with File scoping for handling **items** within **root directory** if (items specifically **folders** and **files**) in **Microsoft OneDrive**; **create/delete/metadata** for **Folders** and **upload/delete/metadata** for **Files**.

Using **Microsoft Graph API** again, I wish to do perform the same actions in handling Folders and Files, **create/delete/metadata** for **folders** and **upload/delete/metadata** for **files**, in **Microsoft SharePoint** within the **default Drive** of **root Site** as mention prior for **OneDrive**.

**Problem**

I having the following issues with Microsoft Graph API in using for handling items within default Drive or root Site:

1. Using default Drive ID in handling items within a site's drive.
2. Create/Delete/Get-Metadata of a folder item within default Site's Drive.
3. Upload/Delete/Get-Metadata of a file item within a parent folder.

The following Microsoft Graph API call returns **root site's default drive**'s metadata**:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--write-out 'HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}' \
--silent \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

JSON Response example is:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
  "createdDateTime": "2012-06-12T17:27:56Z",
  "description": "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library.",
  "id": "b!mWxqgLJ9mESqZI4PrP0Gs-F4hgLaCRlCkVuON4nbwzhkKbcyWdM1Tb5WEzNJ0C60",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-03-03T02:39:56Z",
  "name": "Shared Documents",
  "webUrl": "https://docusign2com.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",
  "driveType": "documentLibrary",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "quota": {
    "deleted": 0,
    "remaining": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "used": 0
  }
}
```

**Problem Getting Drive Metadata**

Taking the unencoded **drive_id** for the current default Drive in root Site, `[** DRIVE_ID **]`:

```
"id": "b!mWxqgLJ9mESqZI4PrP0Gs-F4hgLaCRlCkVuON4nbwzhkKbcyWdM1Tb5WEzNJ0C60"
```

Encode **drive_id**, `[** URL-Encoded DRIVE_ID **]`:

```
"id": "b%21mWxqgLJ9mESqZI4PrP0Gs-F4hgLaCRlCkVuON4nbwzhkKbcyWdM1Tb5WEzNJ0C60"
```

Using the **encoded drive_id**, we can get the metadata for that drive another way:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/[** URL-Encoded DRIVE_ID **]" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
  "createdDateTime": "2012-06-12T17:27:56Z",
  "description": "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library.",
  "id": "[** DRIVE_ID **]",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-03-03T02:39:56Z",
  "name": "Shared Documents",
  "webUrl": "https://docusign2com.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",
  "driveType": "documentLibrary",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "quota": {
    "deleted": 0,
    "remaining": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "used": 0
  }
}
```

Next, I tried listing the items within the root Site's default Drive by appending **/items**:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/[** URL-Encoded DRIVE_ID **]/items" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

And it fails:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0a212014-b386-45d9-9c36-bae2dd6cea8f",
      "date": "2020-02-07T06:51:15"
    }
  }
}
```

**API Path Requested**

What is the expected path for getting the list of all items within a default drive's root within root site?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.../v1.0/sites/$site_id/drives/...` for working with drives, I switched to using `.../v1.0/drives/$drive_id/...`, and this worked.

The following Microsoft Graph API request above using `/v1.0/sites/root/drives/[** URL-Encoded DRIVE_ID **]`, the return previously acquired default drive (identified by `[** DRIVE_ID **]`)  metadata:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[** url-encoded DRIVE_ID **]" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--silent \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
  "createdDateTime": "2012-06-12T17:27:56Z",
  "description": "Share a document with the team by adding it to this document library.",
  "id": "[** DRIVE_ID **]",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-03-03T02:39:56Z",
  "name": "Shared Documents",
  "webUrl": "https://docusign2com.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",
  "driveType": "documentLibrary",
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "System Account"
    }
  },
  "quota": {
    "deleted": 0,
    "remaining": 0,
    "total": 0,
    "used": 0
  }
}
```

This returns the root folder of default drive:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[** url-encoded DRIVE_ID **]/root" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--silent \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('[** url-encoded DRIVE_ID **]')/root/$entity",
  "createdDateTime": "2012-06-12T17:27:56Z",
  "id": "[** ROOT_FOLDER_ID **]",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-02-07T16:04:09Z",
  "name": "root",
  "webUrl": "https://docusign2com.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents",
  "size": 27781340,
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "b!mWxqgLJ9mESqZI4PrP0Gs-F4hgLaCRlCkVuON4nbwzhkKbcyWdM1Tb5WEzNJ0C60",
    "driveType": "documentLibrary"
  },
  "fileSystemInfo": {
    "createdDateTime": "2012-06-12T17:27:56Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-02-07T16:04:09Z"
  },
  "folder": {
    "childCount": 5
  },
  "root": {}
}
```

Now with root folder of default drive, the list of children folders can be requested:

```
curl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[** url-encoded DRIVE_ID **]/items/[** ROOT_FOLDER_ID **]/children" \
--request GET \
--verbose \
--silent \
--header "authorization: Bearer [** ACCESS_TOKEN **]" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```